# UDP message not being received on server port

Tags: java, c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am attempting to implement a server - client relationship, all on my local machine.

I have a java program acting as the server, which listens on port 4567.
I have a java program acting as the client, which opens a connection to 127.0.0.1:4567 and sends messages.

This all works, messages are being received .

**Problem**

I implemented the client program in C++ using boost asio to send messages the same way, but it does not work, despite the fact that the message is being sent successfully.

C++ client code that **does not work**:

```
    using namespace boost::asio;
    io_service io_service;
    ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
    ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;

    socket.open(ip::udp::v4());

    remote_endpoint = ip::udp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 4567);

    boost::system::error_code err;
    string msg = err.message();

    socket.send_to(buffer("test_from_c++", 13), remote_endpoint, 0, err);

    msg = err.message();
    cout << err.message() << endl;

    socket.close();
```

Output is

```
The operation completed successfully
```

Also, here is the java client code that **works**.

```
String address = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 4567;
Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
System.out.println("Successfully opened socket for communication to " + address + " on port " + port);

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
out.write("test_from_java");
out.newLine();

out.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: you need an io_service.run() in there

Comment: Where do I place that call?

Comment: @ChrisWard1000 synchronous operations do not require `io_service.run()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ code is correctly sending a *UDP* message.  See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4dd50044b13708f) for a demonstration.

The issue is likely that the server is expecting a *TCP* connection and will not receive data that is using a different transport protocol.  The Java client is using the [`java.net.Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class which provides TCP communication.  On the other hand, the [`java.net.DatagramSocket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html) class is used for UDP communication.

Here is an equivalent TCP client [demonstrated](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65c3ddefc4cd8a7d):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  using namespace boost::asio;
  io_service io_service;
  ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
  ip::tcp::endpoint remote_endpoint;

  remote_endpoint = ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 4567);
  socket.connect(remote_endpoint);

  boost::system::error_code err;
  string msg = err.message();

  socket.send(buffer("test_from_c++", 13), 0, err);

  msg = err.message();
  cout << err.message() << endl;

  socket.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My intention from the start was to only use UDP protocol. I switched the server implementation to DatagramSocket, and it worked.